# Street view panorama doesn't work in a div

Tags: javascript, html, google-street-view, photosphere

I'm trying to embed a street view panorama on a website as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomPanoramaMethod). It works well when I do that :

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

but it doesn't work when i put the #map in a other div, like that :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `width` and `height` map div? If you have blank page instead map, it's probably missing css.

Comment: I have an height of 100% for the #map